# How to get actual values from input field by javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var phone_number = $('input[name=phone_number]').val();
    alert(phone_number);
});
```

The problem is that phone_number always have value on moment when a page was loaded. User may change phone number on the input fied - but script always gets obsolete value. How do I fix this issue?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: You can fire an event and then write the lines of code you have written to do that I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call this function on click of any button
Say you have a button

```
<input type="button" value="Get Value" id="getvalue" />
```

On its click get the value of the field

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#getvalue').click(function() {
         var phone_number = $('input[name=phone_number]').val();
         alert(phone_number);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you write this Get Value Script in document.ready... it always gives you the Default Value..**

Try Get Value Script in any one the **element click event**...

**Because :** here `document.ready = Page Load` Event...

Try this Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/74/

Answer (score 1):

As asifsid88 is right but if user may change phone number then after change phone number you want value of field so instead of click event , i think you should use change event.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have written this script on **document.ready** function, that's why it returns obsolete value.
Put this script in some event i.e click, keypress,blur,onchange etc... So that you can get the changed value.

```
<input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_number" value="Get Value"/>

$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#phone_number').blur(function() {
         var phone_number = $(this).val();
         alert(phone_number);
    });
});
```